# Is muska permissible?

Tags: fiqh

Muska is like words on a paper (with Islamic supplications) and then this gets put into something small and you take it with you or have it under your pillow for protection or good luck. Is this permissible or is it bid'ah?

Comment: What are the words on that paper besides the Islamic supplications?

Comment: @Ahmed it's usually only Islamic supplications.